# how can i access an "HTML DIV" element from my c# class file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I know, few methods like, appending runat="server" attributes to div elements, n then accessing it from codebehind(aspx.cs) file, and also, some jquery javascript methods., but here what I actually need is, to "access the div element in my c# classes which is under appcode folder." Is it possible?

I was thinking whether something like below is possible. Ex:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
public class psv_class()
{
public static void psv_method(Label lb,HtmlDivElement htmldiv)
{
lb.Text="my custom error msg..";
htmldiv.Visible=true;
}
}
```

and then i can call this method in my aspx.cs file, by passing parameters wherever i need..

```
psv_class.psv_method(Label1,StatusMsgDiv);
```

here, above i am sure, HtmlDivElement class doesn't exist in .Net framework, but hoping for some alternate methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in your `using` statements:

```
public static void psv_method(Label lb, HtmlControl htmldiv)
{
    lb.Text = "my custom error msg..";
    htmldiv.Visible = true;
}
```

a HTML div with `runat="server"` attribute is a `HtmlControl` object.

Comment: It could be both, since the Div is in fact an HtmlContainerControl :)

Answer (score 1):

using "HtmlContainerControl" in place of "HtmlDivElement" did fulfill my need in my above example..

Comment: For a richer amount of functionality try using the Panel class